# Sublime Text and VS Code as Note Taking or Diary or Organizer App

Tags: themes, sublime-text-3, color-theme, visual-studio-code, note-taking

Sublime Text or VS Code as Note Taking or Diary or Organizer App, or any Blacked-Theme App.

I really like typing in either Sublime Text and/or VS-Code because of the all-dark-theme those two have.

I spent times searching for extensions to support it as a note-taking app, but really can't find a good one. Can somebody pls point me or tell me a good one.

Or at least tell me any real note-taking app with same all-dark-theme, I really couldn't find one.

Everynote, OneNote, Keynote NF, etc., do not have all-black-themes same as Sublime/VS-Code have.

Also, I have heard about this markdown/markup in VS-Code so I could make some formatting on texts (bold, bigger, smaller, bullet lists, colored, etc.) How to implement it in VS-Code (at least give me some idea or a starting point and I will try to study/learn it).

Also, I would want to disable the automatic tagging, etc (those programming stuffs) that pop-ups everytime I type a word that have meaning on programming.

What extensions or plugins do I need to search to make Sublime and VS-Code to be like a note-taking app, and how?

Thanks,
Marie

Additional Question:

How can I make Sublime/VS-Code to only create/save files in .txt format?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use OneNote with a dark picture as background on my default template.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49qd4.png)

Answer (score 0):

In SublimeText (and any other code editor) you can choose what programming language your file belongs to. Code highlighting depends on this. You can do manually in bottom right corner in status line. If you choose `plain text` then there will be no highlighting at all. You can choose `Markdown` the same way. It is also done automatically when you open file with `.txt` extension editor assume it's plaintext. The same way goes with `.md` extension - editor assume it's Markdown and so on.

To save file as `.txt` you simply add `.txt` to the end of file name when you save it. Code editors work with plaintext files by default, and there are no other options for text files.

There almost no formatting in code editors. All text is the same font and size. There are bold, italic and underline, but they depends from color theme and language you use.

Comment: Do you know of any Color Theme which is good for Note Taking? Thanks.